# What do I do about drawText() and drawRect() drawing in two different locations when given the same coordinates?

Tags: android, canvas, paint, drawrect, drawtext

I'm trying to draw a text to the screen and then have a rectangle in the same spot to account for knowing when the user clicks within it (and clicks the text).  Problem is when I put the text in one spot on the screen and the rectangle in the same spot, it apparently isn't in the same spot.  Is there some setting I need to set somewhere?

```
private final String[] options = {"Start", "High Scores", "Help", "Quit"};

public void draw(final Canvas g)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        width = HORIZONTALOFFSET * 3 + spaceInvadersTitle.getWidth();
        height = GamePanel.getScreenHeight() / 4 - (75 * 2 + TEXT_SIZE) / 2 + i * 75;

        rect[i] = new Rect(width, height, width + 325, height + TEXT_SIZE);
        g.drawRect(rect[i], paint);
        g.drawText(options[i], width, height, paint);
    }
}
```

[image: misaligned rectangles]

FYI "width" and "height" are more like x- and y-coords.  The horizontal alignment is not the problem - just the vertical.  If you'll notice from the code, I'm setting the starting x- and y-coordinates for the drawText and drawRect the same exact position, but that's not how they're showing on the screen.  Instead it seems the drawText is using that position as a lowerleft anchorpoint or something like that.  Is that how it works?  If so, how do I change that?

Also, if you have any suggestions on how to approach listening for when the user clicks on a drawn text, I'm all ears.  This is the easiest way I could think of, and how I do it in regular desktop Java.

Comment: The coordinates that you pass to the `drawText()` method are the coordinates of the leftmost point of the baseline of the text. You want to change the y-coordinate in the `drawText()` call to `height + TEXT_SIZE`.

Comment: DrawText draws a bit differently (from baseline) than other draw calls (from top left corner). You should first get text bounds from Paint object and use those to draw your rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I should have noticed that.  Still, I don't see why they do it like that.  I guess maybe because the base of the letters all line up and not the tops.  Anyway, if you make that a formal answer, I will give you the chosen answer (green checkmark).